# Can not solve Kramberg equation

Tags: gps, position

The problem is posed as follows:

"There are 5 satellites, need to find the points: x,y,z."

There is an equation:

```
23 ^ 2 = (x-12) ^ 2 + (y-25) ^ 2 + (z-24) ^ 2
25 ^ 2 = (x-(-53)) ^ 2 + (y-19) ^ 2 + (z-21) ^ 2
19 ^ 2 = (x-82) ^ 2 + (y-25) ^ 2 + (z-24) ^ 2
26 ^ 2 = (x-87) ^ 2 + (y-25) ^ 2 + (z-(-24)) ^ 2
23 ^ 2 = (x-12) ^ 2 + (y-25) ^ 2 + (z-(-57)) ^ 2
```

I can not solve this matrix. It is necessary to count x, y, z.

I tried to solve a lot of options, but I did not get.

Comment: If this is not directly solvable (as implied on Mathematics SE), you might have to look at doing a least squares fit.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is only about mathematical operations. This is an equation system with 3 variables. If you google this, you can find lots of pages describing solutions, like this [page](https://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-2/how-to-solve-system-of-linear-equations/solving-systems-of-equations-in-three-variables) or this [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-home/alg-system-of-equations/alg-systems-with-three-variables/v/systems-of-three-variables).

You have to express one variable and then use substitution, then express second variable and use substitution and so on.